# Going deeper with xpath node()

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to find the surrounding text of all hyperlinks within paragraphs on Wikipedia pages, and the way I'm doing that involves using the xpath `tree.xpath("//p/node()")`. Things work fine on most links, and I'm able to find most things that are `<Element a at $mem_location$>`. However, if a hyperlink is italicized (see example below), the xpath `node()` only sees it as an `<Element i at $mem_location>`, and doesn't look any deeper.

This is causing my code to miss hyperlinks, and messes up the indexing for the rest of the page.

Ex:

```
<p>The closely related term, <a href="/wiki/title="Mange">mange</a>,
is commonly used with <a href="/wiki/Domestic_animal" title="Domestic animal" class="mw-redirect">domestic animals</a> 
(pets) and also livestock and wild mammals, whenever hair-loss is involved. 

<i><a href="/wiki/Sarcoptes" title="Sarcoptes">Sarcoptes</a></i> 
and <i><a href="/wiki/Demodex" title="Demodex">Demodex</a></i> 
species are involved in mange, both of these genera are also involved in human skin diseases (by 
convention only, not called mange). <i>Sarcoptes</i> in humans is especially 
severe symptomatically, and causes the condition known as 
<a href="/wiki/Scabies" title="Scabies">scabies</a>.</p>
```

The `node()` grabs "Mange", "Domestic animal", and "Scabies" properly, but pretty much skips "Sarcoptes" and "Demodex" and screws up the indexing, since I'm filtering out nodes that are `<Element a at $mem_location$>` and not `<Element i at $mem_location$>`.

Is there a way to look deeper with `node()`? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about it.

Edit: My xpath is `"//p/node()"` right now, but it's only grabbing the outermost element layer. Most of the time it's `<a>`, which is great, but if it's wrapped in an `<i>` layer, it only grabs that. I'm asking if there's a way I can check deeper, so that I might be able to find the `<a>` within the `<i>` wrapper.

The relevant code is below:
      tree = etree.HTML(read)

```
titles = list(tree.xpath('//p//a[contains(@href,\"/wiki/\")]/@title')) #extracts the titles of all hyperlinks in section paragraphs
hyperlinks = list(tree.xpath('//p//a[contains(@href,\"/wiki/\")]/text()'))
b = list(tree.xpath("//p/b/text()")) #extracts all bolded words in section paragraphs
t = list(tree.xpath("//p/node()"))

b_count = 0
a_count = 0
test = []
for items in t:
print items
items = str(items)
if "<Element b" in str(items):
  test.append(b[b_count])
  b_count += 1
  continue
if "<Element a" in str(items):
  test.append((hyperlinks[a_count],titles[a_count]))
  a_count +=1
  continue

if "<Element " not in items:
  pattern = re.compile('(\t(.*?)\n)')
  look = pattern.search(str(items))

  if look != None: #if there is a match
    test.append(look.group().partition("\t")[2].partition("\n")[0])

  period_pattern = re.compile("(\t(.*?)\.)")
  look_period = period_pattern.search(str(items))
  if look_period != None:
    test.append(look_period.group().partition("\t")[2])
```

Comment: What is the code you are using so far?

Comment: In `t` variable, you want all b and a items? what exactly you want in `t` variable ?

Comment: `t` holds all elements that is parsed by xpath, so it's a list of everything that is in the paragraph. Below is `print t[:15]`
 
 

`[<Element b at 0x7f59228cf248>, ' is an ', <Element a at 0x7f5922947368>, ' with ', <Element a at 0x7f59229473b0>, '.', <Element sup at 0x7f59228cf2d8>, '\n', 'There are several complications with the terminology:\n', 'Acariasis is a term for a ', <Element a at 0x7f5922947440>, ', caused by mites, sometimes with a papillae (', <Element a at 0x7f59228cf3b0>, '), and usually accompanied by severe ', <Element a at 0x7f5922947488>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of a direct xpath that can do the trick, but you can always loop through the contents and filter out the elements like this -

```
for i,x in enumerate(t):
    if x.tag == i:
        aNodes = x.find('a')
        if aNodes is not None and len(aNodes) > 0:
            del t[i]
            for j, y in enumerate(x.findall('/nodes()')): #doing x.findall to take in text elements as well as a elements.
                t.insert(i+j,y)
```

This would handle multiple `a` inside a single `i` as well, like `<i><a>something</a><a>blah</a></i>`